# Python summing digits in number ,'n'

Tags: python, sum, int, iteration

Im a novice programmer and stumbled upon a problem in codecademy with python.
I get a random positive integer, n, and need to isolate the digits to sum them together and add the sum to a variable ,total

Here is my code so far and remember I'm new to this!:)

```
def digit_sum(n):
    total = 0
    while len(str(n)) > 0:
        total = total + n%10
        n -= n//10
```

Comment: Infinite loop? even `'0'` has length 1.

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues in your code:

- The function does not return a value. Add `return total` at the end.
- You should not continue while `len(str(n)) > 0` because that will always be true: any number converted to string will have at least one character. Instead, just verify `n > 0`
- `n` should not be adjusted by subtraction, but by division: `n //= 10`

So here is the corrected code:

```
def digit_sum(n):
    total = 0
    while n > 0:
        total = total + n%10
        n //= 10
    return total
```

Not an issue, but you can shorten `total = total + n%10` by `total += n%10`

Comment: Okay i see thank you very much. The math was wrong with the subtraction and i learnt a new thing about strings also:)

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration should handle a single digit. The easiest way of doing this is by dividing it by 10 each in each iteration:

```
def digit_sum(n):
    total = 0
    while n > 0:
        total += (n % 10)
        n //= 10
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem here is that your loop does not terminate (I could easily figure that out myself here, but in general, please tell in your question what the problem is).

Let's try to debug it using a print:

```
def digit_sum(n):
    total = 0
    while len(str(n)) > 0:
        print(n)
        total = total + n%10
        n -= n//10
```

When I call it with some argument, I get a lot of `9` in my console, indefinitely. That's because `9//10` is `0`, because it truncates the result of the division.

And actually, the math you tried to use are not correct. You do not want to substract one tenth of `n` to `n`, because that would give you nine tenths of `n`.
What you want is to take one tenth of `n`.

So, do this: `n = n//10` and not this: `n -= n//10`